# how to have a list of clickable links from a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, hyperlink

I have a database were the information from the database comes on to my website (code below).

On another page I have a text box were you type in a new table, it creates a new table and sends the table name to another table which stores all the tables. I want to view all the tables from that table list but have them when i click on them take me to view the other tables.

I have very little experience with databases and PHP but I'm thinking if I can store the table variable in cookies and then initiate it in another document and have it resets every time the user returns to the page which has all of the other tables they can view.

But I still don't know how to create links to that other doc which runs all the other tables.

This text below is in a file called db_results.php

```js
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "myDB";


    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<p>". $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"] . "</p>";
         }
    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

this code views the results and is just called index.php

```html
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function() {
                $("#load_results").load("db_results.php");
            }, 1000);
        });

    </script>

    <div id = "load_results"></div>
```

the code is not setup for links yet but the links would go into last name and the viable name into first. please message me for any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the echo to echo a link.

If it really goes into your last name field it would look something like this:

```
echo "<p>". $row["firstname"]. " <a href="url">" . $row["lastname"] . "</a></p>";
```

But it wouldbe better if you created another field in your table to insert the link into.

Comment: thank you, how would i link certain links to certain tables without creating new php files for every table?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here, but It doesn't seem right to create so many tables. Please explain what you want to achieve with a example.

Comment: i am trying to achieve like a messaging site were you can create new chats and have a list of all of the chat rooms.

Comment: you will have to do some database normalization. You asked how to display a link using a field in a database. So if you create a table with all the chat rooms, you could use that table to display all the chatrooms and make them clickable using the code provided

Comment: how would i have all the chatrooms without creating new files for each database

Comment: I would recommend you follow some tutorials on database design and php before continuing. I will be to much to answer your questions like this. But assume you have a table just like your `MyGuests` table that contains all the chatrooms, you could display them just like your displaying your guests.